# change unselected tab color of tablayout dynamically

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

i am using databinding to change the color of the selected tab of tab layout

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["tabIndicatorColor", "context"])
fun setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(tabLayout: TabLayout, color: Int, context: Context) {
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getColor(context, color))
}
```

and setting it from the tabLayout view

```
  <variable
        name="professionalTypeColor"
        type="Integer" />

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tl_images"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                tabIndicatorColor="@{professionalTypeColor}"
                context="@{context}"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="8dp"
                app:tabPaddingStart="8dp" />
```

what i did until here is exactly as i wanted it to be, but for the unselected tabs i couldn't make a databinding Adapter for it so i change its color dynamically ,
i tried using

> ```
>                 app:tabBackground="@color/grey"
> ```

or

> ```
>                 app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab_indicator"
> ```

but this need to be predefined color or a drawable with two colors (selected,unselected) which is not my desired result,
my question is how to make a databinding adapter to set the tabBackground dynamically , ( i couldn't find a setter in tablayout with attribute of tabbackground )

Answer (score 0):

Create a style in style.xml and call in xml layout like below

```
 <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">

    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondaryText</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Call here

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
      **style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"**
                app:tabGravity="fill" />
```

Comment: that didn't help change the background color of tabs dynamically ,app:tabBackground
this only works for the textColor